# I am trying to Duplicate Keyframes, and Its not working. What do I do?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have about 5 seconds of animation, and I'm trying to copy and paste the Keyframes to make the Animation longer (it's a looped animation).

Whenever I try to <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, the Keyframes don't duplicate.

[image]

P.S. Not sure if this is important, but I got the animation from "Mixamo".

Comment: Unfortunately I am an unable to see the image you attached

Comment: if you want to repeat the animation again and again, you wouldn't copy the animation, but use the cycles modifier. So in graph editor, select all keyframes (you want to cycle) hit N -> modifiers -> add modifier -> cycles

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you select the keyframes in an animation editor (timeline, graph, dopesheet, whatever). Keep your mouse cursor in that editor as Blender use its position to know what you want to do do.

Then press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, move your mouse to chose where to create the new keyframes (you can type the amount of frames too), and hit <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> or <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to validate.

Comment: Im sorry, didnt work.